# How do I enable backup(snapshot) on redis elasticache t2.medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, redis, amazon-elasticache

I was able to create a snapshots of my m1.small caches but the backup button is disabled when I select my t2.medium. Is there a way for me to enable backup of a t2.medium redis elasticache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For Redis (cluster mode disabled) clusters, backup and restore aren't supported on cache.t1.micro nodes. All other cache node types are supported.

User Guide (API Version 2014-09-30): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html#backups-constraints

You can get around this limitation of 'backup and restore' on certain instance types by creating your Redis Cluster with 'Cluster Mode' enabled.